# Code works on RS232, on RS485 gets stuck after a while

Tags: javascript, html, console, serial-port, rs485

As in title. While using this code to send just simple colors on click.

```
function clickColor(event)
{
    event = event || window.event; // handle IE issues
    var target = event.target || event.srcElement; // more IE issues
    var xmlhttp;
    var lineSelect = document.getElementById("lineSelector");
        xpw.serialTransmit({line: lineSelect.value,
        message: target.style.getPropertyValue('background-color')+"\r\n"});
        document.getElementById("textBox").style.color = target.style.getPropertyValue('background-color');
}
```

While connecting the deivce (Lantronix EDGE) through RS232 everything works perfectly, but while using RS485 after sending around 15 messages I'm receiving only nulls in console. No colours. Reseting the device fixes the problem for another few messages.

Comment: Most RS-485 use hardware handshaking.  Are you sure your 485 line isn't looking for a handshake?

Comment: I can't really answer that cause I honestly don't know. How can I make the the connection with handshake? I'm new to this.

Comment: @Baddack, forgot to notify

Comment: Unforuntately, I don't know Javascript but here is a quick rundown: `RequestToSend`- Request-to-Send (RTS) hardware flow control is used. RTS signals that data is available for transmission. If the input buffer becomes full, the RTS line will be set to false. The RTS line will be set to true when more room becomes available in the input buffer. `RequestToSendXOnXOff` - Both the Request-to-Send (RTS) hardware control and the XON/XOFF software controls are used.

Comment: `XOnXOff` - The XON/XOFF software control protocol is used. The XOFF control is sent to stop the transmission of data. The XON control is sent to resume the transmission. These software controls are used instead of Request to Send (RTS) and Clear to Send (CTS) hardware controls.

Comment: I would look up those hardware handshaking protocols with Javascript and see if you can figure out how to enable/disable them.